# Calling a Range (as a variable) in a different Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have set a Range as a variable

```
Set Range_Count = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
```

And now I'm trying to call it in a WorksheetFunction using VBA without needing to select the worksheet

```
'This is what I don't want to do anymore
Sheets(1).Select
Count_Product = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range_Count, "<>")

'This is what I'm wondering if it's possible to be done
Count_Product = Application.WokrsheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(2).Range_Count, "<>")
```

But It doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works:

```
Set Range_Count = Sheets(2).Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)) 'full qualify the range with it's sheet
Count_Product = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range_Count, "<>") 'then use the range
```

Comment: So I can't use the same range (set as a variable) for different worksheets?

Comment: Once you set a range, you must reset the range variable for every sheet. If is the same range you can loop through the sheets but also your `Count_Product` will be overwritten.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's not possible to do as I thought it could.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What was your goal?

Comment: I have found what I wanted to do!

`
Sheets(2).Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range_Count, "<>")
`

This solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

So, I just solved it by putting the sheets before `Application` like this

```
Dim Range_Count As Range
Set Range_Count = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

Sheets(2).Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range_Count, "<>")
```

Easier than I thought